# How do you embed a Tweet in a Blazor page?

Tags: c#, twitter, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Is there an accepted method to embed a Tweet or other social media post in a Blazor page? The  tags in Twitter embeds and most other give a compiler error in Visual Studio.

Here's what Twitter tells you to paste into your source code:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Is there an accepted method to embed a Tweet or other social media post in a <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/Blazor?src=hash&amp;ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">#Blazor</a> page? The &lt;script&gt; tags in most embeds give a compiler error in Visual Studio.</p>&mdash; BenjaminCharlton (@Benjami63766584) <a href="https://twitter.com/Benjami63766584/status/1296819523304271873?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">August 21, 2020</a></blockquote> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

What is the correct way to do this on a Blazor page please?

Comment: What error are you seeing in the IDE?

Comment: Script tags should not be placed inside components because they cannot be updated dynamically. To fix this, move the script tag to the 'index.html' file or another static location. For more information see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=872131

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the script from this [page](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/javascript-api/guides/set-up-twitter-for-websites) and place in your Index.html

Remove the script from what you have or use there API to generate without script.

Here is a component that will accept the embed string as a parameter:

```
@using Microsoft.JSInterop

@((MarkupString)RawHtml)

@code {

    [Inject]
    public IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string RawHtml { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("twttr.widgets.load");
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Brian. How do I use the RawHtml property of your component please? Your OnAfterRenderAsync method doesn't appear to reference that property.

Comment: Its passed to the component via a Parameter like any component. You don't need it you cant just put the pasted html in the markup area. The script changes the appearance. Its best to wrap it in a div or something as well to help the renderer remove it.

Comment: I've made a blazor library. To wrap all this up. Ill try an finish it in the morning and drop a link. It can optionally use a ChildContent for the pasted Markup.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I'll be interested to see it when it's finished!

Comment: Hey Brian, did you ever made that wrapper, perhaps?
I'm trying to implement Twitter timeline feeds into our webpage, would like to have few of them available, as separate UI components. I am struggling to find a way around that very same error with including script, and my project's Index is a razor component, not html file.
I made code snippets via publish.twitter.com tool...
Thank you.